# spring data specification with denormalized table

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a property table that holds property values and an FK to the main table, such as:

```
Catalog_FK | display_order | prop_name | prop_value
     1     |      1        |  title    |   myTitle
     1     |      2        |  desc     |   ths describes stuff
```

and so on...I want to search on a list of properties and return all catalog entries that have those properties

I have tried everything when creating a specification, but can't figure out how to do it...I am able to write a specification on the property to filter a single property (and get the catalog from the ManyToOne relationship) but I can only filter a single property, I need to be able to filter a list of properties.

I added the specification to the catalog (which contains a OneToMany relationship to the props) I tried to create a property by hand and pass it in to see if it was contained in the catalog list, but received a hibernate exception saying the property didn't have a key.  I assume because Catalog_FK + Display_Order create a compound key.  but I don't want to search on those...    ...so, I'm really not sure how to approach this...any advice would be appreciated (Sorry, I don't have code now as I'm at home and code is at work...but I can't stop thinking about this issue)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own `Specification`. First, you'd create a `Specification` to filter those `Catalog` elements, that contain a given `Property`. You can use `ConstraintBuilder.exists` for that.

Then you can use `Specifications.and` to combine multiples of those.

Comment: The problem I'm having is I want to know if the catalog contains a property that has certain values, regardless of the ID of the property...the property I'm using for a comparison is passed through a rest call...not an actual DB Entity.  I receive a hibernate error indicating that the property is a `unsaved transient instance` and an exception is thrown from the `Specification`

Comment: You can build the subselects to your needing. Don't use the property as a parameter but the name or value or whatever you need. About the exception: We won't be able to help with that if we don't see your actual code.